# Upload images with thumbnails to folder and add path to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, image-uploading, image-upload

I am willing to add or update images with auto thumbnails to folder and add path to MySQL database. I tried this code with this. I am able to upload images to folder and saving path to database but I can't able to generate thumbnails please help me on this.

```
<?php
ob_start(); 
include('include/connect.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
             $file='uploads/'.$row['image'];
             $thumbs='uploads/thumbs/'.$row['image'];
             @unlink($file);
             $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
             $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
             $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
             $image_name=time().".".$ext;
             $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
             $Uploadthumbs = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/thumbs/".$image_name);                
        }
        else
        {
            $image_name=$row['image'];
        }

         $sqlAdd ="update  tbl_emp set name='".$name."', image='".$image_name."'  where id=".$_GET['id'];
         mysql_query($sqlAdd);
         header("Location:add.php?id=".@$_GET['id']."&msg=success");
         exit;
    }       
}
else
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
            $image_name=time().".".$ext;

            $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
            $Uploadthumbs = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/thumbs/".$image_name);            
        }
        $sqlAdd = mysql_query("insert into tbl_emp(name,image) VALUES('$name','$image_name')");
        header("Location:add.php?msg=success");
        exit;
    }
}
    ob_end_flush();

    if(isset($_GET['msg']))
    {
        ?>
        <div style="color:red;padding-bottom:10px;" class="form-message" align="center"><b>Task completd successfully.</b></div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: LIke the name says `move_uploaded_file()` **moves** the file from the temporary folder to whereever you say to move it. Therefore the second time you run it, the temporary file is not there anymore. Relpace the second `move_uploaded_file()` with a `copy()`

Comment: by doing this i got a copy of image into thumb folder with same size now i need to resize it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to generate thumbnails, use class.upload.php .
With it you can resize your images in many ways.

http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm